# Passing a state from child component to parent component in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I have two components named **Food** and **Order**. In the Food component user can select a food. I'm storing the selected food in a state. The Food component is rendered inside Order component. Here user can proceed to order their food.

My question is how to pass the selected food from Food component to Order component?

Comment: Define a function inside order component and pass it to Food as props. When user select food call that function with selected food state as parameter

Answer (score 2):

From your explanation, it looks like the `Order` component needs access to the state inside its child `Food` component.
This is classic [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) IMO.

You need to keep the state representing selected food in the `Order` component and pass it down as prop.

If this is not what you were looking for, please share the work you have done so far in a codesandbox preferably. Will make it easier to help then :)

Comment: How to do the lifting state up with react hooks?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an event e.g `onFoodSelect` in `Food` component which will get called Everytime user selects a food and pass the  selected food as a parameter...

Then listen in the event from `Order` component

```
// Food
// ....
return <>
      {items.map(item=>(
         <div key={item+Math.random} onClick= {_=>props.onFoodSelect(item)}>{item}</div>)
      }
     </>
// ....

// Order
// ...
return <Food
             onFoodSelect={item=>{
                  // Do whatever
             }}
           />
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

React, by design, does not have access to its child state. You have to create a callback and pass it as props to `Food`:

```
const Food = ({ onChange }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState("");

  function handleOnChange(e) {
    setState(e.target.value);
    onChange(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <select onChange={handleOnChange} value={state}>
        <option value="pizza">Pizza</option>
        <option value="burger">Burger</option>
      </select>
      Selected: {state}
    </>
  );
};

const Order = () => {
  function handleOnFoodChange(value) {
    console.log(value);
  }
  return <Food onChange={handleOnFoodChange} />;
};
```

[image: Edit amazing-noyce-d60t2]

Comment: Can you alter this code for food selection with radio buttons?

Comment: <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio1" autocomplete="off" onClick={setFood( "Pizza")}/>. How to do it for this case?